# Create a function to change the margin of a ggplot based on the labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a funciton called gg_format_width() which automatically formats the width of a plot based on the length of the labels on the y-axis.

Ideally I would want to add gg_format_width to an existing plot much like I would add the theme or a geom. So for example like so:

```
p <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = plot_data, ggplot2::aes(x = value, y = var_label)) +
    ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + gg_format_width()
```

Since I need to access the length of the labels I need access to the labels on the y-axis.
So far I have found a to access those with strwidth and ggplot_build which works well. However, to use these in the function I need access to the plot from within the function. Is there a way to do this without having to pass the plot as an argument to the function?

I have tried using last_plot which works well in most cases. However, in the following case using last_plot would have unwanted effects:

```
p <- ggplot(xyz)

p1 <- ggplot(uvw)

p <- p + gg_format_width
```

In this case getting the last_plot would result in gg_format_width using information from p1 to format the width of p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `+` to modify a ggplot object then you can create a function that generates an object with a custom S3 class, then all you need to do is write a method for the generic `ggplot_add` function. You haven't said exactly how you want to use the string widths, so let's just print them out to demonstrate the principle:

```r
library(ggplot2)

gg_format_width <- function(...) {
  structure(list(...), class = "format_width")
}

ggplot_add.format_width <- function(object, plot, object_name) {

  y_labels <- layer_scales(plot)$y$get_breaks()
  plot.new()
  y_sizes <- setNames(strwidth(y_labels), y_labels)
  print(y_sizes)
  
  return(plot)
}
```

Now we can use `gg_format_width()` as we would with a standard ggplot function call:

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Species)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  gg_format_width()

#>     setosa versicolor  virginica 
#>  0.0699841  0.1016265  0.0871382
```

[image]

We can see that our function has access to the plot object, and if necessary can use information about the plot itself to modify it.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. If I want to pass additional argument to gg_format_width such as for example plot_width. How would I go about that?

Comment: If you call `gg_format_width(plot_width = 1.2)` then your `ggplot_add.format_width` function will have access to the number 1.2 via `object$plot_width`

Comment: Okay, so just for better understanding of the concept here.. with ggplot_add.format_width I add a method to the ggplot objects in my environment. And from gg_format_width I then call that method. Is that correct?

Comment: @P.Luchs no. What you are doing is creating a new type of object (essentially an empty list) that is of a particular class - the class 'format_width'. The point in doing this is that when this object is added to a ggplot, it triggers the `ggplot_add.format_width` function, which allows you to modify the `ggplot`. This is exactly the mechanism that ggplot uses itself to be able to add coords, themes, layers, scales etc using the `+` mechanism. Using the `...` argument (see update) you can make the `format_width` object contain information for the function to use.